# NCover for ASP.net web application

Tags: asp.net, ncover-explorer

I have developed an asp.net web application, ( a simple e-commerce website)
I want to use the NCover tool to run coverage tests. But i cant find any documentation which will guide me through to use NCOver for my asp.net web application. Can SOmeone please help me with the documentation or steps.

Answer (score 0):

Quick search on the NCover website:

http://ncover.com/support/docs/v3/how-to/code-coverage-of-asp-net-applications-on-iis

Comment: I have not published my website on the IIS, does that matter? and ok, here I have to download selenium also :(

Comment: You need to be using IIS yes, can you not install it on your local development machine ?

Comment: Yeah, its blocked in my company, and since this is just a learning project we cant request for that. is there a work around for htis?

Comment: Potentially using IIS Express instead ?